# I tried solving reverse linkedlist on my own way. please spot the problem reversing the linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Hi everyone Can you tell me why this code not working for reversing linkedlist I tried my own way to solve but don't get what am I doing wrong

```
 def reverselist(self):
    temp=self.start
    cur=None
    prev=None
    nxt=None
    while(temp!=None):
        nxt=temp.next
        cur=temp
        cur.next=prev
        prev=cur
        temp=temp.next
```

Comment: prev=None ... cur=temp ... cur.next=prev ... temp=temp.next, now temp is None and it leaves the while. also in the very end you have to adjust the self.start pointer

Comment: hi but i assigned temp to cur so temp value will not be changed so why would it be none unless list is at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these assignments:

```
    cur=temp
    cur.next=prev
    prev=cur
    temp=temp.next
```

The one that really mutates the list, is `cur.next=prev`. There you make the `next` pointer point backwards. But then *after* that change, you do `temp=temp.next`. So you are taking the *modified* `.next` value here.

If that does not clarify it, then realise that `temp == cur` (the first assignment), so also `cur.next == temp.next`. If you assign a new value to `cur.next`, then `temp.next` will be that new value.

The solution is to perform `temp=temp.next` *before* you change the `next` pointer:

```
    cur=temp
    temp=temp.next
    cur.next=prev
    prev=cur
```

Or, which I find a bit clearer, but really is the same thing:

```
    cur=temp
    temp=cur.next
    cur.next=prev
    prev=cur
```

Here you clearly see the pattern: what you have at the right side of the assignment, becomes the left side in the next assignment. This shows clearly that you first *read* the current value of a variable or property, and then *write* a new value to it.

NB: you never *read* `nxt`, so you don't need that variable.

### Assign all at once

In Python you can make multiple assignments in one go, which saves you a variable (`prev`) because *all* expressions at the right side are evaluated before any of the assignments happen:

```
    temp.next, cur, temp = cur, temp, temp.next
```

Comment: hi thank you so much can I know your insta id chat personally

Comment: I don't chat. Sorry.

Comment: alright i just wanted to seek advice from you . if that's not you carryon thanks for the explaination though it was all clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
def reverselist(self):
    temp=self.start
    cur=None
    prev=None
    nxt=None
    while(temp!=None):
        nxt=temp.next
        temp.next = prev
        prev = temp
        temp = nxt
    self.start = prev
```

Comment: You need to point the prev node to head at the end outside the while loop

Comment: yes you are correct can you explain clearly why cause I dont get it clearly??

Comment: That is because after you while loop executes , the whole list is reversed yet your list won’t have any head , so there won’t be any starting point and you won’t be able to print it.